# Accessing a webpage within a webpage using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have written a Python script that parses the data of a webpage using beautifulsoup. What i want to do further is to click the NAME of each person on page, access their profile, then click on the website link on that page and scrape the email id ( if available ) from that website. Can anyone help me out with this? I am new to beautifulsoup and python so i am unable to proceed further. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!
The kind of link i am working on is:
https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/agentname-john

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv




#####################  Website
#####################           URL

w_url = str('https://www.')+str(input('Please Enter Website URL :'))





####################### Number of
#######################           Pages

pages = int(input(' Please specify number of pages: '))




#######################  Range
#######################         Specified
page_range = list(range(0,pages))




#######################  WebSite
#######################          Name ( in case of multiple websites )
#site_name = int(input('Enter the website name ( IN CAPITALS ) :'))



#######################  Empty
#######################        List
agent_info= []




#######################   Creating
#######################            CSV File
csv_file = open(r'D:\Webscraping\real_estate_agents.csv', 'w')

csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['Name and Number'])





####################### FOR
#######################    LOOP
for k in page_range:
    website = requests.get(w_url+'/pg-'+'{}'.format(k)).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website,'lxml')


    class1 = 'jsx-1448471805 agent-name text-bold'
    class2 = 'jsx-1448471805 agent-phone hidden-xs hidden-xxs'



    for i in soup.find_all('div',class_=[[class1],[class2]]):

        w = i.text
        agent_info.append(w)





#####################  Reomiving
#####################            Duplicates

updated_info= list(dict.fromkeys(agent_info))





#####################   Writing Data
#####################               to CSV

for t in updated_info:
    print(t)
    csv_writer.writerow([t])
    print('\n')




csv_file.close()
```

Comment: `I have written a script that parses the data of a webpage using beautifulsoup` Please [edit] your question and post code trials?

Comment: Can you give us the code you have tried? There is no email address to be scraped on that page nor on the details page!

Comment: Yes I have posted. If you guys kindly keep it as simple as possible, because i am not good with classes and functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be more efficient (and less lines of code) if you grab the data from the api. It also appears the website emails are within that too, so if needed, no need to go to each of the 30,000+ websites for that email, so you can get it all in a fraction of the time.

The api also has all the data you'd want/need. For example, here's everythin on just 1 agent:

```
{'address': {'line': '1101 E 78TH ST STE 300', 'line2': '', 'city': 'BLOOMINGTON', 'postal_code': '55420', 'state_code': 'MN', 'state': '', 'country': 'US'}, 'advertiser_id': 2121274, 'agent_rating': 5, 'background_photo': {'href': 'https://ap.rdcpix.com/1223152681/cc48579b6a0fe6ccbbf44d83e8f82145g-c0o.jpg'}, 'broker': {'fulfillment_id': 3860509, 'designations': [], 'name': 'BRIDGE REALTY, LLC.', 'accent_color': '', 'photo': {'href': ''}, 'video': ''}, 'description': 'As a professional real estate agent licensed in the State of Minnesota, I am committed to providing only the highest standard of care as I assist you in navigating the twists and turns of home ownership. Whether you are buying or selling your home, I will do everything it takes to turn your real estate goals and desires into a reality. If you are looking for a real estate Agent who will put your needs first and go above and beyond to help you reach your goals, I am the agent for you.', 'designations': [], 'first_month': 0, 'first_name': 'John', 'first_year': 2010, 'has_photo': True, 'href': 'http://www.twincityhomes4sale.com', 'id': '56b63efd7e54f7010021459d', 'is_realtor': True, 'languages': [], 'last_name': 'Palomino', 'last_updated': 'Mon, 04 Jan 2021 18:46:12 GMT', 'marketing_area_cities': [{'city_state': 'Columbus_MN', 'name': 'Columbus', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'Blaine_MN', 'name': 'Blaine', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'Circle Pines_MN', 'name': 'Circle Pines', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'Lino Lakes_MN', 'name': 'Lino Lakes', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'Lexington_MN', 'name': 'Lexington', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'Forest Lake_MN', 'name': 'Forest Lake', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'Chisago City_MN', 'name': 'Chisago City', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'Wyoming_MN', 'name': 'Wyoming', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'Centerville_MN', 'name': 'Centerville', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'Hugo_MN', 'name': 'Hugo', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'Grant_MN', 'name': 'Grant', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'St. Anthony_MN', 'name': 'St. Anthony', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'Arden Hills_MN', 'name': 'Arden Hills', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'New Brighton_MN', 'name': 'New Brighton', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'Mounds View_MN', 'name': 'Mounds View', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'White Bear Township_MN', 'name': 'White Bear Township', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'Vadnais Heights_MN', 'name': 'Vadnais Heights', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'Shoreview_MN', 'name': 'Shoreview', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'Little Canada_MN', 'name': 'Little Canada', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'Columbia Heights_MN', 'name': 'Columbia Heights', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'Hilltop_MN', 'name': 'Hilltop', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'Fridley_MN', 'name': 'Fridley', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'Linwood_MN', 'name': 'Linwood', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'East Bethel_MN', 'name': 'East Bethel', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'Spring Lake Park_MN', 'name': 'Spring Lake Park', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'North St. Paul_MN', 'name': 'North St. Paul', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'Maplewood_MN', 'name': 'Maplewood', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'city_state': 'St. Paul_MN', 'name': 'St. Paul', 'state_code': 'MN'}], 'mls': [{'member': {'id': '506004321'}, 'id': 416, 'abbreviation': 'MIMN', 'type': 'A', 'primary': True}], 'nar_only': 1, 'nick_name': '', 'nrds_id': '506004321', 'office': {'name': 'Bridge Realty, Llc', 'mls': [{'member': {'id': '10982'}, 'id': 416, 'abbreviation': 'MIMN', 'type': 'O', 'primary': True}], 'phones': [{'ext': '', 'number': '(952) 368-0021', 'type': 'Home'}], 'phone_list': {'phone_1': {'type': 'Home', 'number': '(952) 368-0021', 'ext': ''}}, 'photo': {'href': ''}, 'slogan': '', 'website': None, 'video': None, 'fulfillment_id': 3027311, 'address': {'line': '1101 E 78TH ST STE 300', 'line2': '', 'city': 'BLOOMINGTON', 'postal_code': '55420', 'state_code': 'MN', 'state': '', 'country': 'US'}, 'email': 'tony@thebridgerealty.com', 'nrds_id': None}, 'party_id': 23115328, 'person_name': 'John Palomino', 'phones': [{'ext': '', 'number': '(763) 458-0788', 'type': 'Mobile'}], 'photo': {'href': 'https://ap.rdcpix.com/900899898/cc48579b6a0fe6ccbbf44d83e8f82145a-c0o.jpg'}, 'recommendations_count': 2, 'review_count': 7, 'role': 'agent', 'served_areas': [{'name': 'Circle Pines', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'name': 'Forest Lake', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'name': 'Hugo', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'name': 'St. Paul', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'name': 'Minneapolis', 'state_code': 'MN'}, {'name': 'Wyoming', 'state_code': 'MN'}], 'settings': {'share_contacts': False, 'full_access': False, 'recommendations': {'realsatisfied': {'user': 'John-Palomino', 'id': '1073IJk', 'linked': '3d91C', 'updated': '1529551719'}}, 'display_listings': True, 'far_override': True, 'show_stream': True, 'terms_of_use': True, 'has_dotrealtor': False, 'display_sold_listings': True, 'display_price_range': True, 'display_ratings': True, 'loaded_from_sb': True, 'broker_data_feed_opt_out': False, 'unsubscribe': {'autorecs': False, 'recapprove': False, 'account_notify': False}, 'new_feature_popup_closed': {'agent_left_nav_avatar_to_profile': False}}, 'slogan': 'Bridging the gap between buyers & sellers', 'specializations': [{'name': '1st time home buyers'}, {'name': 'Residential Listings'}, {'name': 'Rental/Investment Properties'}, {'name': 'Move Up Buyers'}], 'title': 'Agent', 'types': 'agent', 'user_languages': [], 'web_url': 'https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/John-Palomino_BLOOMINGTON_MN_2121274_876599394', 'zips': ['55014', '55025', '55038', '55112', '55126', '55421', '55449', '55092', '55434', '55109'], 'email': 'johnpalomino@live.com', 'full_name': 'John Palomino', 'name': 'John Palomino, Agent', 'social_media': {'facebook': {'type': 'facebook', 'href': 'https://www.facebook.com/Johnpalominorealestate'}}, 'for_sale_price': {'count': 1, 'min': 299900, 'max': 299900, 'last_listing_date': '2021-01-29T11:10:24Z'}, 'recently_sold': {'count': 35, 'min': 115000, 'max': 460000, 'last_sold_date': '2020-12-18'}, 'agent_team_details': {'is_team_member': False}}
```

**Code:**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import math

# Function to pull the data
def get_agent_info(jsonData, rows):
    agents = jsonData['agents']
    for agent in agents:
        name = agent['person_name']

        if 'email' in agent.keys():
            email = agent['email']
        else:
            email = 'N/A'
        
        if 'href' in agent.keys():
            website = agent['href']
        else:
            website = 'N/A'
            
        try:
            office_data = agent['office']
            office_email = office_data['email']
        except:
            office_email = 'N/A'
        
        row = {'name':name, 'email':email, 'website':website, 'office_email':office_email}
        rows.append(row)
    return rows

rows = []   
url = 'https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/api/v3/search'
headers= {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {'nar_only': '1','offset': '','limit': '300','marketing_area_cities':  '_',
           'postal_code': '','is_postal_search': 'true','name': 'john','types': 'agent',
           'sort': 'recent_activity_high','far_opt_out': 'false','client_id': 'FAR2.0',
           'recommendations_count_min': '','agent_rating_min': '','languages': '',
           'agent_type': '','price_min': '','price_max': '','designations': '',
           'photo': 'true'}

# Gets 1st page, finds how many pages yoyu'll need to go through, and parses the data   
jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
total_matchs = jsonData['matching_rows']
total_pages = math.ceil(total_matchs/300)
rows = get_agent_info(jsonData, rows)
print ('Completed: %s of %s' %(1,total_pages))

# Iterate through next pages
for page in range(1,total_pages):
    payload.update({'offset':page*300})
    jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
    rows = get_agent_info(jsonData, rows)
    print ('Completed: %s of %s' %(page+1,total_pages))

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output: Just the first 10 rows of 30,600**

```
print(df.head(10).to_string())
                name                       email                                 website                   office_email
0       John Croteau           jcrot45@gmail.com  https://www.facebook.com/JCtherealtor/      1worcesterhomes@gmail.com
1  Stephanie St John       sstjohn@shorewest.com   https://stephaniestjohn.shorewest.com     customercare@shorewest.com
2     Johnine Larsen     info@realestategals.com               http://realestategals.com  seattle@northwestrealtors.com
3    Leonard Johnson  americandreams@comcast.net                 http://www.adrhomes.net     americandreams@comcast.net
4  John C Fitzgerald           john@jcfhomes.com                 http://www.JCFHomes.com                               
5  John Vrsansky  Jr     John@OnTargetRealty.com           http://www.OnTargetRealty.com        john@ontargetrealty.com
6      John Williams    jwilliamsidaho@gmail.com        http://www.johnwilliamsidaho.com               mpickford@kw.com
7        John Zeiter          j.zeiter@ggsir.com                                                         info@ggsir.com
8      Mitch Johnson  mitchjohnson1316@gmail.com                                            miaroberson@creedrealty.com
9          John Lowe           jplowe4@gmail.com                http://johnlowegroup.com  thedavisgrouponline@gmail.com
```

Comment: You guys are simply amazing !! Just one query though, how to select the number of pages? ( which parameter controls that to be precised? )

Comment: control that in 2 ways. you'll see in the `payload` dict: `'limit'` and `'offset'`. Limit is set at `300` (which I think is the max). That just says how many agents to return in the request. the `'offset'` says where to "offset" the returns. So you can play with those. Right now I have the pages set as `"total_pages"`, which calculates how many agents, divided by 300 since you get 300 per page. So you could just change that variable to what ever number you like, and thats how man pages you'll get, and limit will say how many be page. Does that make sense?

Comment: So again, if you want ALL agents, leave as is. If you want a certain amount, and for a certain amount of pages, change the `'limit'` to then number of agents you want per page, and `total_pages` to how many pages you want. So if you want 60 agents returned, change `'limit':'20'`, and `total_pages = 3` or whatever multiple gets you 60. Myadvice is you want to do as few requests as possible, so I'd just do `'limit':'60'`, `total_pages = 1`

Comment: Yes pretty much! Thanks again for such an easy to understand approach. :)

Comment: Hello again friend. Is there a way to pass list of items to a certain parameter in the payload? ( e.g. I have thousands of postal codes whose data I want to fetch. I have searched but only able to find the single parameters ). It would be a great help!

Comment: it doesn't look like passing in a list of postcodes works. you could pass in a city and or/state though if you need a wider, more narrowed search.

Comment: They protected this endpoint behind a JWT token... Anyone figure out how to generate that jwt token? The JWT token that is generated has a 5 second timeout: ```{
  "exp": 1653534519,
  "sub": "find_a_realtor",
  "iat": 1653534514
}```

Answer (score 1):

I have used requests[(docs)](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) instead of beautifulsoup, but still I tried to keep it as simple as possible

I have implement for the mentioned website specifically.I am filtering based on other attributes instead of class names and extracting the agent name from URL.

I am populating the set `agentWebsites` with required information in format *(agentName, collection (tuple) of agentWebsite mentioned in their profile)*.

I am populating the set `agentEmails` with required information in format *(agentName, collection (tuple) of emails mentioned in their websites)*.

> I am **not using a dict** with *agentName* as **key** and
> *websites/emails* as **values** since the agentName may not be unique and it can't be
> used as a key.

**Extracting email from websites:** 
Not all websites have email mentioned in them, some are dummy websites redirecting to some others and some have a form to fill our details to contact them instead of mentioning theirs.

handling exceptions:

1. Some websites are not accessible and they will be printed in output.
2. Some websites are taking lot of time to render, they are also being printed in output. you can increase the value of `timeout_length` global variable. when I tried, some websites with this error were getting rende
   red for `200`.
3. any other exceptions like `Connection Error`, etc will be handled by caught by last except and message will be printed to output.

**Code:**

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession, MaxRetries
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
import re
import sys

# Global values to store the links of individual agents, and their websites
agentLinks = set()
agentWebsites = set()
agentEmails = set()

session = HTMLSession()
timeout_length = 10
# urls used
start_url = "https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/agentname-john"
base_url = "https://www.realtor.com"

# Regex to match emails from website
EMAIL_REGEX = r"""(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])"""

# no of pages to be scraped in website
no_of_pages = int(input("Enter no of pages to be scraped:\t"))

# scraping the links of agent profiles, page by page
for page in range(1, no_of_pages + 1):
    r = session.get(start_url + '/pg-' + str(page))

    # get all anchor tags
    agentInfo = r.html.find('a')

    for info in agentInfo:
        # filter only agent profiles and extract links
        if "href" in info.attrs and info.attrs["href"].startswith("/realestateagents/"):
            agentLinks.add(info.attrs["href"])

    print('page', page, 'agents found till now', len(agentLinks))

print('Total agents found till now', len(agentLinks))

# scrape the agentProfile page for the website link
print('---Scraping Website from agent Profile and email from agents Websites---')
agent_count = 0
total_agents = len(agentLinks)

for agentLink in agentLinks:
    emails = set()
    websites = set()
    agentName = agentLink.replace("/realestateagents/", "").split('_')[0].replace('-', ' ').title()

    # print the profile scraping progress
    agent_count += 1
    sys.stdout.write("\rscraping agent{0}'s profile".format(agent_count))
    sys.stdout.flush()

    r = session.get(base_url + agentLink)

    # get all anchor tags
    agentInfo = r.html.find('a')

    for info in agentInfo:
        # filter only website link and extract link
        if "href" in info.attrs and "data-linkname" in info.attrs and info.attrs[
            "data-linkname"] == "realtors:agent_details:contact_details:website":
            agentWebsite = info.attrs["href"]
            websites.add(agentWebsite)

    if websites:
        agentWebsites.add((agentName, tuple(websites)))

        # print the email scraping progress
        sys.stdout.write("\rscraping agent{0}'s websites for emails".format(agent_count))
        sys.stdout.flush()

        # scrape EMAILS in the websites
        for website in websites:
            try:
                r = session.get(website)
                r.html.render(timeout=timeout_length)
                for re_match in re.finditer(EMAIL_REGEX, r.html.raw_html.decode()):
                    if '/' not in re_match.group():
                        emails.add(re_match.group())

            except ConnectionError:
                print('\rcannot connect to', website)
            except MaxRetries as mr:
                print("\r", mr.message.replace('page.', website), sep='')
            except:
                print("\rUnexpected error for site", website, ":", sys.exc_info()[0])
            finally:
                # print the email scraping progress
                sys.stdout.write("\rscraping agent{0}'s websites for emails".format(agent_count))
                sys.stdout.flush()

        # after scraping all websites, add all emails found
        if emails:
            agentEmails.add((agentName, tuple(emails)))

# agentWebsites is a set of tuples of format (agentName, agentWebsite url)
print("\r\nTotal Agent websites scraped", len(agentWebsites))
print(agentWebsites)

print("\nNo of agents with emails scraped", len(agentEmails))
print(agentEmails)
```

**example output:**

```
Enter no of pages to be scraped:    2
page 1 agents found till now 20
page 2 agents found till now 40
Total agents found till now 40
Scraping Website from agent Profile and email from agents Websites
cannot connect to https://www.david-johnston.kw.com
Unable to render the http://www.reefpointrealestate.com/ Try increasing timeout
cannot connect to http://www.patricia-johnson.com
Unable to render the http://palisadeshomes.com/ Try increasing timeout
Unexpected error for site https://www.jwhomesteam.com : <class 'pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError'>
cannot connect to http://www.stevenjohnson.org
cannot connect to http://www.johnrod.com/
cannot connect to http://www.rodneyjohnson.net
cannot connect to http://john.estatesoflasvegas.com
cannot connect to http://www.teamgoodell.com
cannot connect to http://Hilyardproperties.com

Total Agent websites scraped 32
{('John Mcnamara', ('http://www.ttrsir.com',)),... ('Don Johnson Pc', ('https://www.jwhomesteam.com',))}

No of agents with emails scraped 11
{('John Genovese And Richard Lester', ('connect@mycitycountry.com',)), ... ('John "Dan" Bethel', ('therealtygroupohio@gmail.com', 'danbethelteacher@gmail.com'))}
```

**Note:**
we can use `r.html.find('a', containing='<text>')` for filtering, but it didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Thankyou for your time. However this code is retrieving the website urls not the email ids ( if there are any ) on those websites .

Comment: I'm just wondering, if the emails are on this website, why do you need to go to each site to get the email?

Comment: YES! That's almost exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot mate, much appreciated :)

Comment: @chitown88 The email is not present in the same website, the email button will popup a form to give our details.
I know we can use a API, but from question I assumed it must be done using scraping only..